# Reset radial blur to center

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, blur

I recently changed the radial blur center to a corner and I would like to set it back to default (in the center). Is there any keyboard shortcut?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hold down <kbd>⌘</kbd> and the Cancel button will change to Default.

[image]

[image]

Click Default

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Restarting Ps will reset to default

(If you know another method, please answer and i'll mark your answer)